# How to call method from other module in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My app is like this:

```
angular.module('app', [
    // other includes
    'ui.bootstrap'
])
```

in my directive I'm working on :

```
angular.module('app').directive('DateFields','DatepickerController', ['$timeout', 'DatepickerController', function ($timeout, DatepickerControlle) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: 'path to calendar.html',
    scope: {
        element: "=",
        flowParameterMap: "=?"
    },
    controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$timeout', function (scope, element,  $timeout) {
        if (!scope.element)
            return;
        scope.overlayClick = function (e)
        {
            scope.isOpen = true;
            var input = $(e.currentTarget).next();
            $timeout(function () {
                $(input).focus();
                $DatepickerController.isOpen = true;
            });              

        }


    }]
};
}]);
```

As you can see I'm trying from code change value of datepickers isOpen variable to show datepicker binded to the other dom object.
But all my tries end in "is undefined" error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your directive:

```
scope: {
    element: "=",
    isOpen: "=",
    flowParameterMap: "=?"
},
```

Now you should be able to chagne isOpen value.

Comment: Sry : `Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.3/ng/areq?p0=fn&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%string`